# Tikz block diagram with angled arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

How can I make some thing like this? Especially with the angled arrows (the lines going to 'Scan Operation') instead of 90 degree -| style lines.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried something? If you did, you can post here what you tried and explain why it did not work. People tend to get more help here when they show that they made some effort to achieve what they're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\definecolor{strange}{RGB}{230,244,253}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw,fill=strange,minimum height=2.5em},
    font=\sffamily,>=stealth]
 \begin{scope}[start chain=A going below,node distance=1em,
    local bounding box=buffers]
  \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
  {\node[block,on chain,minimum width=8em]{Buffer};
  \draw[<-,thick] (A-\X.west) -- node[above]{$m_\X(t)$} ++ (-4em,0) ;}
 \end{scope} 
 \node[right=6em of buffers,align=center,inner sep=0.5pt,fill=strange,
    circle,draw] (SO) {Scan\\operations};
 \foreach \X in {1,...,4} 
  {\draw[->,thick] (A-\X.east) -- node[above]{$m_\X(t)$} ++ (4em,0) -- (SO);}
 \node[right=4em of SO,block,minimum width=6em](M){Modem};
 \draw[->,thick](SO) -- node[above](mc){$m_c(t)$} (M);
 \draw[->,thick](M.east) -- node[above](s){$s(t)$} ++(4em,0);
 \draw[<-] ([yshift=-1ex]mc.south) -- ++ (-1em,-3em)
  node[below,align=center]{Bla\\ bla};
 \draw[<-] ([yshift=-1ex]s.south) -- ++ (1em,-3em)
  node[below,align=center]{Blub\\ blub};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]